# Run function after changing buffers with helm-list-buffers

Tags: helm, hooks

`helm-list-buffers` brings up a list of buffers to select. I'd like to run a function after buffer selection. What's the method to do this?

Comment: What's the function you want to run?

Comment: @xuchunyang Custom function that maximizes current window height. It's like the reverse of `balance-windows`.

Answer (score 2):

Customize the option `helm-type-buffer-actions`, you can take a look at its default value for examples.